# Why do I still need to regenerate static content in developer mode?

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

I've noticed that in developer mode whenever I enable an extension, or a theme, I will have to regenerate the static content. Here's an example of [such a case](https://magentowizard.wordpress.com/2020/02/21/path-cannot-be-used-with-directory/).

According to the magento 2 documentation it shouldn't be required to regenerate static content in developer mode. Often times I have to force the regeneration.

Any ideas why the static content has to be regenerated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ask myself the same question.
And the same with di:compile on developer mode. I spent hours thinking my code was broken, but it was just missing di:compile. Normally I work on production mode and I am used to run these commands after changes. But isn't the idea of developer mode to be faster for... development without having to wait for compile?

Comment: Yes! I have those exact same problems too. Like the [official stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/plugins/magento/install#manual) extension. Docs say in production run `di:compile` and `static-content:deploy` ... but I still have to do that in development mode in order for it to work.

Comment: Usually, I don't need to deploy static content. I've found that removing `frontend`, `adminhtml` and `_cache` from `pub/static` to be sufficient. If `deployed_version.txt` exists, remove that as well.

Comment: Yeah, you don't really have to run SCD (static content deploy) for visual stuff. But still gotta run di:compile and sometimes upgrade. If you run upgrade without --keep-generated, you might have to run SCD again. Go figure. :D

Answer (score 0):

When you install or enable a new module, it might load new JavaScript, CSS, layouts, and so on. To avoid issues with static files, you must clean the old files to make sure you get all the changes for the new module.

The static view files deployment command enables you to write static files to the Magento file system when the Magento software is set for `production mode.`

The term static view file refers to the following:

“Static” means it can be cached for a site (that is, the file is not dynamically generated). Examples include images and CSS generated from LESS.

“View” refers to presentation layer (from MVC).

By default, the static content deployment tool can be run only in production mode.

-f option is used to deploy files in any mode forcefully.